# Customizing the JSON received from Web API

Tags: c#, json

I need to add one more node to Json string.

Following is the code from where I am reading the data.

```
var url = "https://xyz_12232_abc/0908978978979.json";
var sys = new WebClient();
var content = sys.DownloadString(url);
```

I received following output from above code:

```
{
 "2312312312313":
                {
                "emailId":"abc@gmail.com",
                "model":"XYZ001",
                "phone":"+654784512547",
                "userName":"User1"
                },
"23456464512313":
                {
                "emailId":"abcd@gmail.com",
                "model":"XYZ002",
                "phone":"+98745114474",
                "userName":"User2"
                },
"45114512312313":
                {
                "emailId":"abcde@gmail.com",
                "model":"XYZ3",
                "phone":"+214784558741",
                "userName":"User3"
                }
}
```

But, I want this output like below:

```
{
 "Records": [
                {
                "UID":"2312312312313":,
                "emailId":"abc@gmail.com",
                "model":"XYZ001",
                "phone":"+654784512547",
                "userName":"User1"
                },

                {
                 "UID":"23456464512313":,
                "emailId":"abcd@gmail.com",
                "model":"XYZ002",
                "phone":"+98745114474",
                "userName":"User2"
                },

                {
                "UID":"45114512312313":,
                "emailId":"abcde@gmail.com",
                "model":"XYZ3",
                "phone":"+214784558741",
                "userName":"User3"
                } 
           ] 
}
```

**Now, how can it be achieved ?**

Comment: Are you using Json.NET?

Comment: The format of the returned json file totally depends on the code that generates the file. You would need to examine how the object is saved, and change it accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) to massage the data into your desired output:

```
var jsonStr = @"..."; // your JSON here
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, JObject>>(jsonStr);

var formattedObj = new
{
    Records = obj.Select(x =>
    {
        x.Value.AddFirst(new JProperty("UID", x.Key));
        return x.Value;
    })
};

// serialize back to JSON
var formattedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formattedObj);
```